# Python 3x - web server - scripts NOT EXECUTING

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my python 3.5 web server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python35
PORT = 80
import http.server
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer( ("", PORT),http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.cgi_directories = ["/"]
httpd.serve_forever()
```

the problem is: files are not executing. web browser simply outputs the contents of the files.

something is missing from it.
I am not that good with python.
just using it to create a web site entirely of bash scripts.

Comment: I added the `httpd.cgi_directories = ["/"]` there myself. it may be flawly done.

Comment: can you install third party libraries like flask?

Comment: @joydeep bhattacharjee, I want simplicity, I do not even want to use python.. but I want to create a web site that is made up of bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This is not that trivial and might need you some days to come with the full blown app. I am giving a small blueprint that you might take as the base to do for further development using python and [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

To keep the app simple I am assuming the shell scripts are kept in the same directory as the app. To build the app you can use flask framework which is a microframework which makes the building of simple apps very easy in python. Python has a `subprocess` module which can be called to execute the shell script in the back. The root url will serve the files in the directory along with the links to the files and if the files are clicked the user will be routed to another url which will have the output of the bash script which is clicked.

Thus your project must have two files. The python file which we can call my_server.py and a template file: home.html kept in the templates folder, to handle the showing of the different files in the root folder. So your root folder will look like below. script.sh is a sample script file that is kept there for testing. You will have your own script files there.

```
drwxrwxr-x templates
    -rwxr--r-- home.html
-rw-rw-r-- script.sh
-rwxr--r-- my_server.py
```

contents of home.html:

```
<html>
<body>
  <ul>
    {% for i in data: %}
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('script_file', filename=i)}}">
        Files: {{ i }}
      </a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

contents of my_server.py

```
import os
import subprocess

from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def get_data():
    def file_in_dir():
        for entry in make_tree(get_root_dir()):
            yield entry
    return render_template('home.html', data=file_in_dir())


@app.route('/<filename>')
def script_file(filename):
    if ".sh" in filename:
        shell_script =  {'file_path': get_root_dir(), 'filename': filename}
        subprocess.call("bash {file_path}/{filename} > out.txt".format(**shell_script), shell=True)
        with open("out.txt") as f:
            contents = f.read()
        return contents
    else:
        return "Not an executable bash script"


def make_tree(path):
    lst = "No files"
    try: lst = os.listdir(path)
    except OSError:
        pass #ignore errors
    return lst


def get_root_dir():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I hope this will be enough to get you started.